# Using Cmake to build ssh.dll with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2017, libssh

I am a beginner in C++ and I am trying to build  `ssh.dll` on Windows 32bit using Visual Studio 2017 and `cmake`. I have downloaded the latest version of `libssh` and tried to build `ssh.dll` from the source by using `cmake` after configuring and generating as per the recommended steps.

After generating, I opened the libssh solution file with Visual Studio 2017 and build it but while compiling it gave few missing library errors which I resolved by adding those libraries to the VC path.

After adding those libraries, it started giving me around 600 compilation errors like below related to syntax (but syntax looks correct in these library files) .

Is there a way or suggestion by which I can successfully resolve them and create .dll file ?

Below are some of those errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'session'   ssh_shared  c:\apps\mvs15\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\libssh\priv.h   196 
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'channel'  ssh_shared  c:\apps\mvs15\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\libssh\callbacks.h  64  
Error   C2059   syntax error: ';'   ssh_shared  c:\apps\mvs15\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\libssh\callbacks.h  64  
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'fd'    ssh_shared  c:\apps\mvs15\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\libssh\libssh.h 656 
Error   C2059   syntax error: ')'   ssh_shared  c:\apps\mvs15\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\libssh\libssh.h 597 
Error   C2081   'socket_t': name in formal parameter list illegal   ssh_shared  c:\apps\MVS15\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\libssh\poll.h   135 
Error   C2059   syntax error: '}'   ssh_shared  c:\apps\MVS15\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\libssh\session.h    203 
Error   C2146   syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'fd'    ssh_shared  c:\apps\MVS15\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\include\libssh\socket.h 36  
Error   C2059   syntax error: ';'   ssh_shared  c:\apps\mvs15\vc\tools\msvc\14.10.25017\include\libssh\callbacks.h  64  
Error   C2037   left of 'iqmp' specifies undefined struct/union 'rsa_st'    ssh_shared  C:\apps\vcpkg\downloads\libssh-0.7.6.tar\libssh-0.7.6\src\libcrypto-compat.c    77  
Error   C2037   left of 'dmq1' specifies undefined struct/union 'rsa_st'    ssh_shared  C:\apps\vcpkg\downloads\libssh-0.7.6.tar\libssh-0.7.6\src\libcrypto-compat.c    76
```

In order to resolve it, I also tried to replace the questionable library files with other version of these library files, but without any luck. What can I try next?

Comment: Did you install the dependent zlib, openssl libraries?

Comment: Yes. Actually I installed `zlib` and `openssl` libraries before generating the solution with `cmake-gui.exe`. But I am not sure why I had to include libraries manually in my VC folder, both for `openssl` and `libssh` header files.

Comment: How did you install them? Windows has no built-in convention for installing c / c++ libraries.

Comment: @VTT So I downloaded `libssh` source code and installed `zlib`, `openssl` and `cmake`. Ran `cmake-gui.exe` by poitning it to the `src` sirectory of `libssh` downloaded, configured it and generated the build. After that I could see the libssh_solution file in my build folder which opened in Visual Studio 2017 for compiling. Initially, there were libraries missing and causing errors related to missing library. Those were '`libssh`, 'openssl` `zlib` and `config.h`. I added them manually into my VC path after which on compiling again, I started getting the above errors which I mentioned in the OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just git a git clone and build it successfully.

Here is how I did it.

```
vcpkg install zlib:x64-windows openssl:x64-windows 
# in vcpkg installed directory:
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM=x64 "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
```

For static linking include
-DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x86-windows-static

Open the solution file in Visual Studio 2017 and it successfully builds.

```
2>   Creating library ssh.lib 
2>ssh_shared.vcxproj -> ....\build\src\Debug\ssh.dll
========== Build: 7 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 4 skipped ==========
```

If you want to build for 32 bit architecture

```
vcpkg install zlib openssh
in the cloned source code
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:/dev/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
```

Comment: Thanks Darmian. Let me try it out.

Comment: Will it be vcpkg install openssl:x64-windows instead? Please let me know.

Comment: You need to add :x64-windows if you want to build for 64 bit architecture. If this was helpful please mark my answer as correct. Cheers!