# Compiling a static program in Visual Studio (VCPKG / CMAKE)

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, vcpkg

I am trying to create static program in Visual Studio, where I end up with a single executable that I can deploy to other PCs.

I am using VCPKG to static download libraries, as per the instructions here:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/vcpkg-updates-static-linking-is-now-available/

In the following post, the answer to the question is to use VCPKG and then CMAKE
[Using Cmake to build ssh.dll with Visual Studio 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54456213/using-cmake-to-build-ssh-dll-with-visual-studio-2017/54456831#54456831)

My question is with regards Cmake. If VCPKG downloads and creates folders that my project links to. What's Cmake for and why would I need to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's Cmake for and why would I need to use it?

https://cmake.org/ read the text below the logo.

It can be used to generate a project files for different build system, like make, msbuild, ninja etc.
It also can be used as a general scripting language.

You don't need to use it but it is highly encouraged for consuming other dependencies.

vcpkg however will download cmake since it is used as a scripting language within vcpkg.